# update-grub brings back manually removed menu entries

Tags: grub2

There are two menu entries that I want to remove from my GRUB boot menu, so I commented them out of the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-FCD5-F73E' {
    ...
}
# menuentry 'Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/sdb1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-844ea196-bb78-4f18-b7fd-58be4c491e92' {
#   ...
# }
# submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/sdb1)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-844ea196-bb78-4f18-b7fd-58be4c491e92' {
#   menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/sdb1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-37-generic.efi.signed--844ea196-bb78-4f18-b7fd-58be4c491e92' {
#       ...
#   }
#   ...
# }
```

I then run `sudo update-grub` as usual. However, doing so brings back the menu entries, which get uncommented from the `grub.cfg` file.

How can I get the menu entries to stay commented out after running `update-grub` so that they don't show up in the boot options? I realize that not running `update-grub` will keep out the menu entries, but I'd like to get rid of this unwanted behaviour from `update-grub` so that I don't have to manually comment out the menu entries each time I run this command.

Notes:

- Both `update-grub` and `update-grub2` bring back the unwanted menu entries.
- The unwanted menu entries are duplicates. I already have menu entries for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is not a good way to do this. There's a good chance you'll break it, and even if you don't, you'll probably find it reverted when a system update rolls in later at some point.

Explicitly adding a `GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST` value to `/etc/default/grub` is not a great solution either, as it requires you to manually find and block out the `UUID`s of every bootable disk you could possibly plug into your machine. I'm also not sure that editing files in `/etc/default` is the preferred way to customize your Linux distribution's behaviour.

It's also not necessarily a great idea to disable `/usr/bin/os-prober` outright, as other programs could potentially depend on it for other purposes.

The best solution, then, is probably to work within the configuration files belonging `grub` and specifically purposed for manual human customization.

**On `Debian` and `Ubuntu`, the automatically generated boot entries seem to be handled by `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`.**

**Simply delete this file or disable execution permissions on it, then regenerate the `grub` configuration to get rid of the automatically added entries.** This worked on my machine:

**`sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`**

**`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`**
**`sudo update-grub`**

You can watch the output of the configuration generation and check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to verify that the extraneous entries have been removed before rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

#

## DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

#

## It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates

## from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub

#

The proper way to edit grub entries is via `/etc/default/grub` and the files in `/etc/grub.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

This entries are generated from os-prober. Os-prober:

> Description: utility to detect other OSes on a set of drives  This
>   package detects other OSes available on a system and outputs the 
>   results in a generic machine-readable format.

Take a look in /usr/bin there is a shell-skript from package os-prober.

You can remove the executable flag from the skript, Or deinstall os-prober.

Edit: Wrong place I mean /usr/bin/os-prober. Nott in /etc/grub.d

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove entries generated by *os-prober* using following Grub configuration:

1.Check UUIDs for the disks using the command:

```
sudo blkid
```

2.Update */etc/default/grub* file by adding the line:

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="UUID_OF_DISK_YOU_DONT_WANT_SCAN1 UUID_OF_DISK_YOU_DONT_WANT_SCAN2"
```

3.Regenerate Grub configuration:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

NOTE: *grub2-mkconfig* due to some reasons still displays information about the ignored disk, but it wasn't generated to final */boot/grub2/grub.cfg* file.